# Get chromes console log via Ruby WebDriver

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This question has been previously answered in Java ([Get chrome's console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log))

However, I am using the Ruby bindings and was wondering if that provided similar functionality?

I have looked at the Ruby source code but cannot see any mention or reference to LoggingPreferences.

By the way, I am using RemoteWebDriver and passing in a desired capability object.  Presumably I want to set the logging preferences in that object, but I am struggling to see where.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apologies for late response.

I originally achieved it by adding the following to Webdriver;

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class Options

      #
      # Returns the available logs for this webDriver instance
      #
      def available_log_types
        @bridge.getAvailableLogTypes
      end

      #
      # Returns the requested log
      #
      # @param type [String] The required log type
      #
      # @return [Array] An array of log entries
      #
      def get_log(type)
          @bridge.getLog(type)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

When "required" this resulted in the following being supported;

```
driver.manage.get_log(:browser)
```

However, Version 2.38 of the selenium ruby gem exposes the logging API (although experimental).

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Logging

Therefore, from 2.38 onwards the following should work WITHOUT the above extension;

```
driver.manage.logs.get :browser
```

Comment: does not work for me (selenium-webdriver-4.0.0.alpha6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code as well

require 'selenium-webdriver'

console_logs = @browser.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)
puts = console_logs

ReportBuilder.build_report

Use command **-f json -o my_report_file.json**  to generate reports.