# watir get console error

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

How I can check browser console if there are any error?

I'm following the watir ubuntu tutorial:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get "http://watir.com"
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to. Errors from commands you run should be automatically forwarded to your ruby code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check browser console output on Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043406/check-browser-console-output-on-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Easy , add this lines at the end
console_logs = browser.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)
puts console_logs