# How to keep 'Developer Tool' window open while my testing is running

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.
I use the code bellow to open 'Developer Tool' window while my testing is running:

```
robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

It opens the window but closes that right after. How can I keep it open?

I read some about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497718/open-google-chrome-developer-tool-console-while-c-sharp-selenium-test-is-running)
 but I couldn't find my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** run `WebDriver` with opened DevTools in Google Chrome.
Roughly talking: `WebDriver` uses debugger tools for controlling the browser. DevTools are also debugger tools. You can't use both simultaneously.