# How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After tests are run, I want to collect all console error messages displayed in the console(Open Firebug -> Click on Console -> Click on Errors) using Selenium WebDriver + Java.

I tried the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log/18283831#18283831), but it only displays messages for 'Warnings', 'Info' but not for 'Errors'

I want only Console errors like -

[image: Console log]

Can someone please help me how to get those Console log?

Comment: I got console logs using same code you referred i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log/18283831#18283831. Make sure whatever website you looking at has a console errors otherwise it will just give you empty array list and nothing will be printed in eclipse console.

Comment: Hier ist the solution for c#: [How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351421/how-to-get-browser-console-error-messages-using-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp/70351422#70351422)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [JSErrorCollector](https://github.com/mguillem/JSErrorCollector), to collect javascript errors (those coming up in the console) from firefox through java.

it gets as simple as this,

```
final List<JavaScriptError> jsErrors = JavaScriptError.readErrors(driver);
```

Comment: Thank you Deepak, for answer and most importantly pointing to JsErrorCollector git repo!!!

Comment: @deepak 
I am getting error for this package import and whereever JavaScriptError is used in my code, I've added jar file to my project as well
import net.jsourcerer.webdriver.jserrorcollector.JavaScriptError;