# I want to collect all console messages displayed in the console(Open Firebug -> Click on Console -> Click on All) using Selenium WebDriver + Java

Tags: java, selenium

I had tried this [How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593872/how-to-get-browser-console-error-messages-using-selenium-webdriver-java#new-answer)

It didn't work and if works, it works only for Error. I want to retrieve all the content from the Console including Warning, Info and errors.

Comment: What is the log level you have set?

Comment: I am using firefox version34. and currently all is selected in that.