# Capturing browser logs with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to capture browser logs while running automated test cases with Selenium? I found an article on [how to capture JavaScript errors in Selenium](https://web.archive.org/web/20130719045503/http://selenium.polteq.com/en/capturing-javascript-errors-with-selenium-webdriver/). But that is just for Firefox and only for errors. I would like to get all the console logs.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I assume it is something in the lines of:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogType;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ChromeConsoleLogging {
    private WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");        
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
        logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void analyzeLog() {
        LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
        for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
            System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
            //do something useful with the data
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        driver.get("http://mypage.com");
        //do something on page
        analyzeLog();
    }
}
```

Source : [Get chrome's console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log)

Comment: Not sure what browser support you need, but by changing **import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;** and **DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();** you should be able to select it.

Comment: I would be requiring for all the browsers ...thanks for this . It is definitely something which i can work with @Margus

Comment: nice solution for chrome but have you a solution for IE11?

Comment: @Margus If i call `driver.manage().logs().get("browser");` multiple times with in the same driver instance, it fails to capture entries (tried refreshing driver, navigating to another url). Any thoughts or workarounds?

Comment: @user3246489 Last time I checked it wasn't supported for IE see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4802

Answer (score 64):

In a more concise way, you can do:

```
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
```

For me it worked wonderfully for catching JS errors in console. Then you can add some verification for its size. For example, if it is > 0, add some error output.

Comment: awesome, did not have to set desired capabilities and worked like charm.

Comment: nice solution for chrome but have you a solution for IE11?

Comment: IE11 WebDriver should have the same API and act similarly.

Comment: @Stas If i call `driver.manage().logs().get("browser");` multiple times with in the same driver instance, it fails to capture entries (tried refreshing driver, navigating to another url). Any thoughts or workarounds?

Comment: @ManPy what WebDriver implementation (==browser), driver version & language are you using?

Answer (score 25):

As a non-java selenium user, here is the **python** equivalent to Margus's answer:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities    

class ChromeConsoleLogging(object):

    def __init__(self, ):
        self.driver = None

    def setUp(self, ):
        desired = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        desired ['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=desired)

    def analyzeLog(self, ):
        data = self.driver.get_log('browser')
        print(data)

    def testMethod(self, ):
        self.setUp()
        self.driver.get("http://mypage.com")
        self.analyzeLog()
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)

Edit: Keeping Python answer in this thread because it is very similar to the Java answer and this post is returned on a Google search for the similar Python question

Comment: forgot semi colon on analyzeLog function

Comment: Starting from chromedriver, 75.0.3770.8, you have to use `goog:loggingPrefs` instead of `loggingPrefs`.

Answer (score 6):

Adding LoggingPreferences to "goog:loggingPrefs" properties with the Chrome Driver options can help to fetch the Browser console logs for all Log levels.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();    
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
options.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 5):

A less elegant solution is taking the log 'manually' from the user data dir:

1. Set the user data dir to a fixed place:

   ```
   options = new ChromeOptions();
   capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/your_path/");
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   ```
2. Get the text from the log file chrome_debug.log located in the path you've entered above.

I use this method since `RemoteWebDriver` had problems getting the console logs remotely. If you run your test locally that can be easy to retrieve.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Firefox 65 an `about:config` flag exists now so console API calls like `console.log()` land in the output stream and thus the log file (see (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/284#issuecomment-458305621).

```java
profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("devtools.console.stdout.content", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Driver manager logs can be used to get console logs from browser and it will help to identify errors appears in console.

```
   import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries;
   import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry;

    public List<LogEntry> getBrowserConsoleLogs()
    {
    LogEntries log= driver.manage().logs().get("browser")
    List<LogEntry> logs=log.getAll();
    return logs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before launching webdriver, we just set this environment variable to let chrome generate it:

```
export CHROME_LOG_FILE=$(pwd)/tests/e2e2/logs/client.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Add cast `RemoteWebDriver` to `driver` initialize and you will have the **`.setLogLevel`** method:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class PrintLogTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/.../chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //here
        ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setLogLevel(Level.INFO);

        driver.get("https://google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("automation test");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Jun 15, 2020 4:27:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver log
INFO: Executing: get [430aec21a9beb6340a4185c4ea6a693d, get {url=https://google.com/}]
Jun 15, 2020 4:27:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver log
INFO: Executed: [430aec21a9beb6340a4185c4ea6a693d, get {url=https://google.com/}]
Jun 15, 2020 4:27:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver log
INFO: Executing: findElement [430aec21a9beb6340a4185c4ea6a693d, findElement {using=name, value=q}]
Jun 15, 2020 4:27:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver log
INFO: Executed: [430aec21a9beb6340a4185c4ea6a693d, findElement {using=name, value=q}]
...
...
```

At least I've tried it on `ChromeDriver()` and `FirefoxDriver()` and it working fine.

Comment: But isn't this just logging what the driver is doing and not what is in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Browser and performance logging only captures whatever is logged to the console and connection metadata in Chrome (at least, at the time of this writing). To actually get the contents of a fetch request I found some JS ([source](https://blog.logrocket.com/intercepting-javascript-fetch-api-requests-responses/)) to intercept all fetch requests and log the contents to the console which I could then access in browser logs. Total overkill, but hey it works.

```js
const { fetch: originalFetch } = window;
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  let [resource, config] = args;

  let response = await originalFetch(resource, config);

  response
    .clone()
    .json()
    .then((data) => console.log("fetch response:" + JSON.stringify(data)));

  return response;
};
```

Minified

```js
const{fetch:originalFetch}=window;window.fetch=async(...n)=>{let[t,e]=n,o=await originalFetch(t,e);return o.clone().json().then((n=>console.log("fetch :"+JSON.stringify(n)))),o};
```

Usage snippet (Scala)

```scala
driver.executeScript("""const{fetch:originalFetch}=window;window.fetch=async(...n)=>{let[e,o]=n,t=await originalFetch(e,o);return t.clone().json().then((n=>console.log("fetch response:"+JSON.stringify(n)))),t};""")

// action that triggers the fetch

val logEntry = driver.manage().logs().get("browser").iterator().asScala.filter(_.getMessage.contains("fetch response:")).toList
```