# How to get browser logs using selinium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a log which logs using formatting.

```
console.log('%c%s - %s', 'color:blue; font-weight:bold;', msg.type, msg.message);
```

I need to get these logs using selinium.

Using

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
  System.out.println(entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
 }
```

prints

```
INFO xyz/abc/LogService.js 45:14 %c%s - %s
```

instead of printing the value of the object.

How do I get the value of `%s` or `%c` formats in the logs.

Comment: The question is already answered in other topics:
[Capturing browser logs with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431380/capturing-browser-logs-with-selenium)
[Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)

Comment: @Adept, I used the same answer as reference. But this is not printing the value of `%s`.