# How to read the Web Browser Console in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium version 2.46.0.
In order to debug different issues (for example client issues), I would like to get all the web browser console content (errors, warnings ...)

I tried using:

```
LogEntries logs1 = DefaultDriver.getWebDriver().manage().logs().get("client");
```

but got empty log entries...

BTW, I defined the capabilities:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable( LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL );
capabilities.setCapability( CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs );
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver( capabilities );
```

I also tried "driver" and "browser" log types but didn't get the web console content.

Any idea how to do it?

The solutions in the following link didn't work...
[Capturing browser logs with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431380/capturing-browser-logs-with-selenium)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing browser logs with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431380/capturing-browser-logs-with-selenium)

Comment: @Eugene, the solutions described in that link didn't work

Comment: You need `.get(LogType.BROWSER)` **not** `.get("client")`. The capabilities part of your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue with selenium, in C# and i want to show you my workaround which work for every browser(in C#)

First i redirect all logs which web site produce to array which store all logs.
Also i redirrect onerror function to gather all javascript errors

```
    private void BindConsole(IWebDriver webDriver)
  {
     var script = "if (console.everything === undefined) {
        console.everything = [];
        console.defaultLog = console.log.bind(console);
        console.log = function(){
           const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join('_');
           console.everything.push({ 'Type':'Log', 'Datetime':Date().toLocaleString(), 'Value':args});
           console.defaultLog.apply(console, arguments);
        }
        console.defaultError = console.error.bind(console);
        console.error = function(){
           const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join('_');
           console.everything.push({ 'Type':'Error', 'Datetime':Date().toLocaleString(), 'Value':args});
           console.defaultError.apply(console, arguments);
        }
        console.defaultWarn = console.warn.bind(console);
        console.warn = function(){
           const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join('_');
           console.everything.push({ 'Type':'Warn', 'Datetime':Date().toLocaleString(), 'Value':args});
           console.defaultWarn.apply(console, arguments);
        }
        console.defaultDebug = console.debug.bind(console);
        console.debug = function(){
           const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join('_');
           console.everything.push({ 'Type':'Debug', 'Datetime':Date().toLocaleString(), 'Value':args});
           console.defaultDebug.apply(console, arguments);
        }
        window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
           console.error('JavaScript error: ' + message + ' on line ' +
           linenumber + ' for ' + url);
           }
        }";

     ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript(script);
  }
```

Note: you need run this function before your test, because logs won't be captured, and rerun it every time you refresh or change page (on refresh/change all logs will be lost so save them beforehand)

Then, I have object which match log signature in my function

```
 public class LogEntry
   {
      public LogType Type { get; set; }
      public string Datetime { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }
   }

 public enum LogType
   {
      Error,
      Warn,
      Log,
      Debug
   }
```

Then I run following function:

```
 /// <summary>
  /// Check whether new blogs are in browser console and captures them if any. 
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>Logs from browser console</returns>
  public IEnumerable<LogEntry> GetAllConsoleLogs()
  {
     SystemTools.Delay();

     var jsScript = "return console.everything";
     var list = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver.Driver).ExecuteScript(jsScript) as IReadOnlyCollection<object>;
     if (list!=null && list.Count > 0) {
        var token = JArray.FromObject(list);
        ClearConsole();
        return token.ToObject<IEnumerable<LogEntry>>();
     } else {
        return null;
     }
  }
  

  /// <summary>
  /// Delete all previous entrys form browser console, so only new ones will be captured
  /// </summary>
  private void ClearConsole()
  {
     var jsScript = "console.everything =[];";
     ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver.Driver).ExecuteScript(jsScript);
  }
```

This function take array with logs (Json) and with help of .NET Json library converts it to C# object.
I clear object every time i take logs, because I want to examine only new ones, you may remove call of this function and keep logs for all tests if this behaviour is not suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will work or not.
But you can try opening the console with something like below

`Actions builder = new Actions(pbDriver);
        builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F12).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();`

And then use selenium to interact with the console.

OR,

you can try a less elegant solution by taking the log 'manually' from the user data dir:

1. Set the user data dir to a fixed place:

   `options = new ChromeOptions();
   capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/your_path/");
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);`
2. Get the text from the log file chrome_debug.log located in the path you've entered above

Edit:

I actually tried the approach mentioned in the question and it worked for me. The browser I used was Chrome. And as [Siking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124333/siking) pointed out I have used .enable(LogType.BROWSER) to get the logs.
The following code does print all the logs captured during the whole run.

`LogEntries logEntries = pbDriver.manage().logs().get("browser");
        for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
                   System.out.println(entry.getMessage());`

and I just learned that since developer tools is not part of DOM model, selenium can't be used to interact with it. [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) can be used to do this job

Comment: "... use selenium to interact with the console" Can you show a working example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def get_logs2(driver):
# enable browser logging
    #d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    #d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)

    # load the desired webpage
    #driver.get('http://34.90.50.21/')
    #driver.get(driver.current_url)
    a = driver.get_log('browser')

    # print messages
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry)
    print("finished")
    return a
```

or check this: [Robot Frameworkget background call with Robot Framework/selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155774/robot-frameworkget-background-call-with-robot-framework-selenium)