# How to read the web console output with robot framework and selenium?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to read the console output of a webpage, especially I need the POST-GET-PUT ajax calls, with RF and Selenium. I have found some help online but I cannot seem to make it work. the python script I have is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def get_logs2(driver):
# enable browser logging
    #d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    #d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)

    # load the desired webpage
    #driver.get(driver.current_url)
    a = driver.get_log('browser')

    # print messages
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry)
    print("finished")
    return a
```

I call this script from RF, after having done some operations on the webpage. So I need to pass to this function the page exactly how it is after the actions I took. To do that I do:

```
    ${seleniumlib}=    Get Library Instance    SeleniumLibrary
    Log    ${seleniumlib._drivers.active_drivers}[0]
    ${message} =    Get Logs2   ${seleniumlib._drivers.active_drivers}[0]
```

I get as a result and empty message, but I know console is not empty. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Robot Frameworkget background call with Robot Framework/selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155774/robot-frameworkget-background-call-with-robot-framework-selenium) You code suspiciously looks the same, which is not a problem but it simply makes your question a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I actually had my friend Sven ask that question because I did not have an account. I think it is good to close that question and follow up on this one. 
I tried with robot.api logger but since the string is empty it won't print anything.

Comment: I have updated my answer at the other question. The other question cannot be deleted because I have already answered it, this one does not have answers so you can delete this one.

Comment: Great, thank you, the solution worked but now I have a new problem. the console only logs the ajax calls when the "Log XMLHttpRequests" is checked in the developer tools settings. by default it is not, so I do not see the calls in the log. Do you know how to have that box clicked in the "settings" from RF? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using entirely Robot Framework, no additional user library.
The logic is the same.

1. Set the correct browser capabilities to enable logging.
2. Then use the `Get Library Instance` keyword to retrieve the webdriver instance.
3. Call the `get_log('browser')` on the webdriver instance.

---

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
&{browser logging capability}    browser=ALL
&{capabilities}    browserName=chrome    version=${EMPTY}    platform=ANY    goog:loggingPrefs=${browser logging capability}

*** Test Cases ***
Browser Log Cases
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com    Chrome    desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
    ${log entries}=    Get Browser Console Log Entries    
    Log    ${log entries}
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
    
    
*** Keywords ***
Get Browser Console Log Entries
    ${selenium}=    Get Library Instance    SeleniumLibrary
    ${webdriver}=    Set Variable     ${selenium._drivers.active_drivers}[0]
    ${log entries}=    Evaluate    $webdriver.get_log('browser')
    [Return]    ${log entries}
```

Comment: Cannot get this to work with Firefox. I assume I have to change the 'goog:loggingPref' at least. But any ideas where I can find info to do that?
Also getting these errors:
- `[ WARN ] desired_capabilities has been deprecated and removed. Please use options to configure browsers as per documentation.`
- `Evaluating expression '$webdriver.get_log('browser')' failed: WebDriverException: Message: HTTP method not allowed`.

Comment: The error or more like warning is there because you are using a newer selenium and webdriver, which has new parameter naming etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looked a bit at it today again. 
Instead of `desired_capabilities` you need to use `capabilities` in newer versions. But I could not get it to work with Firefox so I instead tested with Chrome and that works, so I can at least use it for debugging the robot test to some extent now.

Comment: @ZpeedTube Yes, this example is for Chrome, the capabilities are Chrome specific. Firefox should have its own way with its own capabilities.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but I could not find any instructions or documentation on how to do it for Firefox.