# How to check the "Log XMLHttpRequests" in the developer tools settings via robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to retrieve the ajax calls (post, get, put...) that show up in the console of a website with Robot Framework. I could do it with [How to read the web console output with robot framework and selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245723/how-to-read-the-web-console-output-with-robot-framework-and-selenium?noredirect=1#comment117142843_66245723).
However  the console only logs the ajax calls when the "Log XMLHttpRequests" is checked in the developer tools settings. by default it is not, so I do not see the calls in the returned log. Do you know how to have that box clicked in the "settings" via Robot Framework/Selenium? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the logging capabilities with the `performance=ALL` in addition to the `browser=ALL` like:

```
*** Variables ***
&{browser logging capability}    browser=ALL    performance=ALL
&{capabilities}    browserName=chrome    version=${EMPTY}    platform=ANY    goog:loggingPrefs=${browser logging capability}
```

Then retrieve the additional logs from the webdriver like:

```
${log entries}=    Evaluate    $webdriver.get_log('performance')
```