# Is there a way to get all the console log and events fired when navigating on a website?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get all the console log and events fired when navigating on a website?

I have tried using the answers on [Capturing browser logs with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431380/capturing-browser-logs-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java/26488661)  but analyzeLog() does not return anything when I use it

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation//chromedriver.exe");
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
 LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
 logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
 options.setCapability("goog:loggingPref", logPrefs);
 options.addArguments("incognito");

 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}



public void log() {
 LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.CLIENT);
 for (LogEntry entry: logEntries) {
  System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
 }
 System.out.println("=======================================================");
}
```

Comment: pretty sure that was supposed to be with an 's' on the end
`options.setCapability("goog:loggingPref", logPrefs);`
should have been ?
`options.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setLogLevel`, but this method available only with `RemoteWebDriver` initialize, and seem like your `driver` initialized by `WebDriver`.

Add cast to your `driver`.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Following import:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your code:

**Step 1:**
Enable `PERFORMANCE` and `BROWSER` logtype

```
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
//To get network log
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
//To get console log
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
```

**Step 2:**

You are using the incorrect setting.

**Incorrect:** 
`options.setCapability("goog:loggingPref", logPrefs);`

**Correct:**  `options.setCapability( "goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs );`

**Step 3:**

Correct the code as per the requirement:

```
//TO get network logs
 LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
//TO get console logs
 LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
```