# Selenium - Is there a way to get an Array from browser Console? (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a hard time finding a solution to my problem.

The scenario is this one: When I open my web app, I get in the browser Console an Array that I need to retrieve in my automation tests. I need this Array, because I need to do some operation based on it.

Is there a way using Selenium and Java to get this Array?

See the attached image for more info:
[image]

Comment: How does the array get there? Do you output it to console from your webapp?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431380/capturing-browser-logs-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java) answer your question?

Comment: This is a QA testing environment and this console.log is send by the development team. I don't have to do anything to get it there, when I open the web application this Array is there

Comment: @Docteur if I use this: LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("browser"); I will only get the Logs, but not the Array. I tried this solution, but this Array is not seen by the LogEntries.

Comment: If on _open the web application this Array is there_, you will definitely get it within the DOM, search for it in the **Elements** tab.

Comment: @DebanjanB This looks to me more like a console.log() output than a DOM element.   Mihai, have you added the capabilities to your webdriver? (Namely 
`LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
        logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);`)

Comment: @DebanjanB this Array is only in the Console tab, he is NOT displayed in DOM. If this Array was in DOM, my life would be so easy. This is why I don't have any idea how to get this.

Comment: @Docteur The query in the expanded form would have cleared all our doubts.

Comment: @Docteur I tried that solution, but I am still unable to get that Array. Even with this solution, I get only the Log entries.

Comment: Do you have access to the webapplication code? @MihaiC If so, could you post it in your question? Without that, it's going to be difficult to understand the problem