# Capturing a number from an alert in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I would would like to capture the number show in the alert shown here. I have tried using the `xpath` to click on it but it does not work. Appreciate any help.

`WebElement attribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='text']//a"));`

Comment: shown where? If it's a popup alert you won't be able to use the method

Comment: It is shown on the user interface... this the the info displayed in the console when I inspect the alert..  <span class="text"> <strong>Success</strong> "You successfully created the file" <a href="FI_FILES/99889878">9988987</a>

Comment: I don't see any screenshot or any console example

Comment: If from browser console, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431380/capturing-browser-logs-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: I tried to add it a screenshot, but it would not let me add one. First time posting here. No idea why it keeps rejecting the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a browser javascript alert, you need to use this:

```
//Click the link to activate the alert
driver.findElement(By.linkText("See an example alert")).click();

//Wait for the alert to be displayed and store it in a variable
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

//Store the alert text in a variable
String text = alert.getText();

//Press the OK button
alert.accept();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this.

Comment: just to clarify, by alert I understand a popup opened by the browser (the ones which you can usually block)

Comment: My script creates a file and after it is saved it displays an alert - with the file number ... I was trying to capture this number to be used to continue the script using it. BTW I used your code and I got  - org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus 'no such alert' (400 expected)   404 --> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such alert' (400 expected).

Answer (score 0):

First, click on the alert link. Then try the below code (it will switch to the present alert-box and fetch the text from that).

```
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```