# Unable to get browser console data with 'showProcessLog: true' for driver type 'chromeDriver', works fine with driver type 'chrome'

Tags: karate

With showProcessLog: true, was able to get browser console data with driver type 'chrome',
if same i tried with 'chromedriver', not working.

- configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', showDriverLog: true, showProcessLog: true, start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' }

Is there any other specific config need to be set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected, there is a fundamental difference with how Chrome (native) and WebDriver works.

But it seems that you can do this if you set the right "capabilities": https://stackoverflow.com/a/25431419/143475

I don't have any examples, but you should be able to figure this out by looking at Karate's documentation (refer [`webDriverSession`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriversession)) and what the "chromedriver" documentation says: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging

Hope you can help the community by doing some research and posting your findings here.