Getting Browser [console] log when running Karate UI tests
I have a webapp that writes some debug information to the Browser log.  I want to be able to capture the browser log so that I can validate this information.  I know we can get browser logs in Selenium like this example:
    if (webDriver != null) {
    LogEntries logs = webDriver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    for (LogEntry entry : logs) {
        LOG.error(entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
    }
}

How can we get access to the browser log from the karate ui code?  I see in the debug log the entries but not sure exactly how to intercept the logs. I've done things in the past to get information from the webdriver like getting a frametree to get a property from the chromedriver i.e.
* def frameTree = driver.send(karate.toMap({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' }))

Is there a way to get the browser console logs?

Not directly supported on Karate yet, do consider contributing.
Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900255/143475
And: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1786
