# Ruby code for configuring Selenium to access JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, ruby, firefox, selenium, console

What is the correct Ruby code for configuring Selenium to access the JavaScript console (i.e., messages writing using `console.log`, `console.error`, `console.info`, etc.)?

I've found several articles with Java, Python, and C# code; but, I'm having trouble getting everything just right for Ruby.

Here is my best guess for Firefox:

```
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
  caps[:loggingPref] = {:browser => :all}
  return Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :desired_capabilities => caps
```

This code doesn't appear to affect anything (I get some logging messages, but not those generated by `console.log`, `console.error`, etc.).  Therefore, I suspect I just have something spelled wrong, or a symbol where I need a string.

Chrome to provide access to `console.info`, `console.error`, and `console.warn` messages by default.  It does not show `console.log` messages.  I assume there is a similar technique for configuring the Chrome driver to return all messages; but, again, I can't find just the right combination of keys, values, symbols, and strings to make it work.

Comment: Here is the post discussing Python code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings

Comment: here is the post discussing Java code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log/18283831#18283831

Answer (score 0):

The capability is called `:logging_prefs` in ruby and the :browser parameter is a string value.

Here's the code (you were quite close!):

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
caps[:logging_prefs] = {:browser => "ALL"}
return Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :desired_capabilities => caps
```

Then you can get the log messages with `driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)`