# Can't get proper console logs from WebDriver (Chrome, C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote following micro-test (it's useless but it's not the case here) in Selenium WebDriver, C#, for Chrome browser:

```
[Test]
    public void T2_API_001_PrintingAlerts()
    {
        pgactions.OpenDataset(driver, settings.dataset); // opening page

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("TsTable.Admin.log('this is error message', true);");
        }

        var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);

        foreach (var log in logs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
```

In debugging console in VS I expect to see (like I see in Chrome browser instance started by WebDriver):

```
[14:02:22.816] Settings valid!
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:22.976] Constructing table...
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:22.976] Validating 32 rows data set...
( some more irrelevant rows )
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:23.375] ...DONE (0.399 sec)
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:24.949] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.060] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.174] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.344] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.477] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.612] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.715] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.809] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:25.993] this is error message
randomTable.js:6711 [14:02:26.089] this is error message
```

but all I get is:

```
------ Run test started ------
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from C:\automated_testing\testTable\TableSelenium.dll
Run started: C:\automated_testing\testTable\TableSelenium.dll
Starting test...
[2016-05-04T12:02:16Z] [All] http://tstable.testsite.com/favicon.ico 0:0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

(the last line matters only, but to be honest - I can't it even see that line in browser(?))

Is the problem in this line?
`var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);` ?

I am aware of that:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6832

but also saw some 'hacks' to gather error logs in different ways. The main case it - I need no errors, but ALL logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get chrome's console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261338/get-chromes-console-log)

Answer (score 5):

The issue was in driver declaration section where `LogLevel` was missing. Now I set `SetLoggingPreference` in `[SetUp]` section:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
driver = new ChromeDriver("path to driver", options);
```

and all logs are printed in debug console :-)

Comment: Works for chrome, but both FF and IE driver threw an exception :( Or does it work for you in IE or FF?

Comment: @AkosLukacs maybe because it's `chrome` options, not `ie` or `ff`? :D