# Chrome Console logs not printing Violations

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with Chrome Driver to crawl websites. 
Need to get everything that gets printed on the chrome console.

Ex: I need Warning and Violation from console below
[image]

`chrome_debug.log` doesn't contain Violations. 
[image]

I have tried passing arg "--verbose", "--v0", "--v1" to chrome driver, 
I have also tried setting LoggingPreferences 
    `loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL)`
with no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: it clearly show that you used the package which is deprecated. So please take the latest package which is available in npm

Comment: Hey Iten Thanks for Response. My issue is I am not able to see [Violations] which we get in console in chrome_debug.log.