# Show or Hide a Div When (Triggered By) Console Displays An Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, error-handling, alert

The issue here is that I'm using a javascript library that has a native error that keeps popping up when a certain group of buttons are pressed too many times (over a specific limit). The page then needs to be refreshed (For now until the native issue is worked out).

I have added this alert to my html, essentially I want it to pop up the moment when the console reports an error. (I am using Chrome)

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;">Please Refresh Page</div>
```

To do this I would essentially use jquery like so:

```
$('.alert').fadeIn()
```

However I am unsure as to how I would trigger that simple jquery call. How could I listen in on the console, and when the console reports an error, call that jquery function to make that alert banner visible?

I have not been able to find a clear answer to my question, hopefully the StackOverflow Community has it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting data from the browser's console using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056737/getting-data-from-the-browsers-console-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970475/get-all-javascript-errors-on-page-javascript-error-handling) I got you're desired effects in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/XmrrOQ) by doing this:

```
window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
    $('.alert').fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :)