# Capturing javascript console.log?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Intercept calls to console.log in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216441/intercept-calls-to-console-log-in-chrome)
> [Can I extend the console object (for rerouting the logging) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277780/can-i-extend-the-console-object-for-rerouting-the-logging-in-javascript)

When my JS app writes to the `console.log`, I want to capture that log message so that I can AJAX that log output to the server. How do I do that?

The code that writes to the log is from external services, which is why I can't just ajax it directly.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can hijack JavaScript functions in the following manner:

```
(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
        // DO MESSAGE HERE.
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };
})();
```

1. **Line 1** wraps your function in a closure so no other functions have direct access to `oldLog` (for maintainability reasons).
2. **Line 2** captures the original method.
3. **Line 3** creates a new function.
4. **Line 4** is where you send `message` to your server.
5. **Line 5** is invokes the original method as it would have been handled originally.

`apply` is used so we can invoke it *on* `console` using the original arguments. Simply calling `oldLog(message)` would fail because `log` depends on its association with `console`.

---

**Update** Per zzzzBov's comment below, in IE9 `console.log` isn't actually a function so `oldLog.apply` would fail.  See [console.log.apply not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538972/console-log-apply-not-working-in-ie9) for more details.

Comment: [Your code will have issues in IE because `console.log` isn't actually a `Function` instance in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538972/console-log-apply-not-working-in-ie9).

Comment: @zzzzBov Interesting.  I assume assigning `console._oldLog = console.log; console._oldLog(message);` would work, but if `console` itself is a hosted object, no changes are guaranteed to stick.  Unfortunately, I don't have IE to test this anymore.

Comment: yea, you could still call `_oldLog` like that. `oldLog = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console)` works for IE9+, but then needs a polyfill for `Function.prototype.bind` for IE8 and below.

Comment: The problem with this method is that we can not capture the log line, it always sends the same line. It would be possible to work around this problem? Thanks

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento raises a good point. How do you preserve the original log line?

Comment: @armensg90 Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32928812/3620727

Comment: Sending `message` to server won't send whole log line if multiple arguments are logged this way `console.log("Server is listening at port", server.address().port);` (only `Server is listening at port` will be in `message`)

Answer (score 27):

Simple:

```
function yourCustomLog(msg) {
  //send msg via AJAX
}

window.console.log = yourCustomLog;
```

You might want to override the whole `console` object to capture `console.info`, `console.warn` and such:

```
window.console = {
  log : function(msg) {...},
  info : function(msg) {...},
  warn : function(msg) {...},
  //...
}
```

Comment: You can't use window.console = { ... } because window.console is a read-only property !

Comment: @Luillyfe but it seems actually working. So what is your comment actually hinting at?

Comment: I wrote a small npm package to do the same. here's a descriptive answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75377394/11565176