# capturing javascript objects sent lo console.log

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

I've used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log) at Stack Overflow to intercept the console log, but I'm unable to get the object so sent together with a text. Consider the following code:

```
var obj={result:true,type:"text"};

(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
        alert(message);  // message does not return the object
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);

    };
})();

console.log("hi",obj);
```

What have I to write in place of `message` in the `alert` code line to get the `obj` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing multiple arguments into your custom `console.log` function, but you are only calling `alert` on the first argument. To fix this, iterate over the arguments to your custom `console.log` function, and call alert on each of the arguments:

```js
var obj={result:true,type:"text"};

(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            alert(arguments[i]);
        }
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);

    };
})();

console.log("hi",obj);
```

If you want to have only one alert that displays all the objects, then you can concatenate their string representations in the for loop and call `alert` only once at the end:

```js
var obj={result:true,type:"text"};

(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function () {
      var result = "";  
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            result += arguments[i] + " ";
        }
        alert(result);
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);

    };
})();

console.log("hi",obj);
```

And finally, if you want to see the contents of the object in your alert, you can call `JSON.stringify()` on each argument before it gets processed.

Comment: Great, now every console call is replaced with not one, but *n* blocking function calls! :) *(The solution is of course correct, technically, but sometimes asking* why *is just as important)*

Comment: @doldt Edited my answer to add a version that alerts once for all the objects. Perhaps this is closer to what you were looking for!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
var obj={result:true,type:"text"};

(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function () {

            alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));

        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);

    };
})();
```