# How can I save the browser console logs to my DB without overriding console.log

Tags: javascript, web, console

I have a very large app that logs a lot of stuff happening in it.

When there's a client error, I want to send a history of X logs to my db.

To do that I first thought of something like that:

```
var yo = {
  log: function() {
    //some logic to save arguments to a queue
    console.log(arguments);
  },
  error: function() {
    //some logic to save arguments to a queue
    //some logic to save queue to db
    console.error(arguments);
  }
}
```

and then use

```
yo.log()
```

instead of

```
console.log()
```

**The problem with this method is that all errors and logs (in chrome's console) debug link directs to the yo function definition instead of the actual error in the code.**

Does anyone know has a better solution to this problem?

Here is a simple example:
http://codepen.io/guysopher/pen/xZKMgG

```js
var yo = {
  log: function() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  }
}

console.log('This shows the right line number!');

yo.log('This shows the wrong line number!');
```

Comment: Try this to get the trace http://stackoverflow.com/a/635852/942223

Comment: This is a good way to get a stack trace after the error has occurred. But I'm looking for a way to wrap the log function without ruining the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably help you.
[Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)

However you need to keep in mind that you overwritten the console.log function.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution but it displays the wrong line number. I need something that will keep the console functionality as is.

Comment: Would combining it with the comment from tiriana work for you.

Comment: The thing is I'm not looking for a stack trace. I want to see the logs I wrote before the error (i.e. what the users did during the session that led to this error)

Comment: You could extract the File from the Stacktrace.

`
(function() {
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
        var error = new Error();
        var stackArr = error.stack.split('\n');
        var fileRef = stackArr[stackArr.length - 2];

        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };
})();`