# redirect Javascript syntax errors and console.log to somewhere else

Tags: javascript, redirect, syntax, console

I'm trying to send whatever would normally appear in the javascript console to my own custom functions.

I've tried the following

```
window.console.error = window.console.debug =  window.console.log
window.console.log=mylog;

function mylog(msg){
    //send it somewhere just using alert as an example
      alert("log="+msg);    
}
console.log("yo");
var x=y;//a syntax error
```

Using the code above I only see the following alert
"yo"

In the console log I see 
"x is not defined"
How do I redirect the syntax errors?

Comment: have u tried using try catch???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onerror` it is designed to catch syntax errors.

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
   alert(message);
}
```

[Offical docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread on this. Note the answer that shows how to "hijack" console.log() and send it wherever you want: [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)