# Capturing JavaScript console.log console.dir, console.table

Tags: javascript, console.log

There is already several questions about capturing or redirecting `console.log`:

- [redirect Javascript syntax errors and console.log to somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759269/redirect-javascript-syntax-errors-and-console-log-to-somewhere-else)
- [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)
- [Intercept calls to console.log in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216441/intercept-calls-to-console-log-in-chrome)
- [Can I extend the console object (for rerouting the logging) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277780/can-i-extend-the-console-object-for-rerouting-the-logging-in-javascript)

When we need to capture all the console messages (console.log, console.dir, console.table ...), is there a simple way to redirect all the functions without "overloading" each?

Edit: this question is about client-side JavaScript

Comment: Would running the node.js program inside another program (kind of like how PM2 and Forever works) be an option? This technique would work with any language - Java, C, assembly, node.js etc.

Comment: It's a client side question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function fake(cb) {
  return (...args) => {
    ... magic capture code...
    cb(...args);
  }
}
Object.keys(console).forEach(k => console[k] = fake(console[k].bind(console)))
```