# How do you add an extra argument to a function call

Tags: javascript

How do you "add" an argument to a function call that you don't call directly?
Specifically, I have

```
(function(){
        //I have the context of `that` here
        var oldLog = console.log;
        console.log = function (message) {
            //I want the context of `that` over here too
            oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
        };
})(that);
```

I'm trying to do this thing where i'm hijacking `window`'s console as done in the accepted answer as shown here: [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)

Because `console.log` has to get called with the `window.console`'s context (since i'm getting the log message from there), I don't have control over how it gets called and the arguments's it gets passed. How do I add `that` into the argument list so that I can have `that` when`console.log` gets called.

TLDR; how do call a function with modified argument list but with same context.

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
(function(that){

    function fn(arg1, arg2){
        alert(arg1);
        alert(arg2);
    }

    function callFnWithExtraArg(arg1){

        // `arguments` is not a real array, so `push` wont work.
        // this will turn it in to an array
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

        // add another argument
        args.push(that)

        // call `fn` with same context
        fn.apply(this, args)
    }

    callFnWithExtraArg('first arg')

})('arg 2');
```