# Filter on multiple columns using one pipe angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I am trying to filter `Array` data based on multiple columns using only one `Pipe`. Right now, It filters first column value. Please check my below code and help me to sort this out.

**My Code:**

```
@Pipe({ name: "dataFilter", pure: false })
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Array<any>, filter: any[]) {
        if (!filter) {
            return value;
        } else if (value) {
            return value.filter(item => {
                for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
                    if (filter[i][1] == undefined) {
                        return true;
                    } else if ((typeof item[filter[i][0]] === 'string' || item[filter[i][0]] instanceof String) &&
                        (item[filter[i][0]].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[i][1]) !== -1)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing data like `dataFilter : [['column1',value1],['column2',value2],['column3',value3]]`.

Comment: Could you provide an example value? Is it on the form: `[{col1:"col1",col2:"col2",col3:"col3"},...,{}]`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a solution using the object passed as multiple columns filter. I found it more convenient then passing a 2D array:

```js
    @Pipe({
        name: 'filter'
    })
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(items: Array<any>, filter: {[key: string]: any }): Array<any> {
            return items.filter(item => {
                const notMatchingField = Object.keys(filter)
                                             .find(key => item[key] !== filter[key]);

                return !notMatchingField; // true if matches all fields
            });
        }
    }
```

Having an array of objects with multiple columns:

```
this.people = [
  {name: 'John', age: 27, sex: 'male'},
  {name: 'Lara', age: 21, sex: 'female'},
  {name: 'Rick', age: 29, sex: 'male'},
  {name: 'Eva',  age: 27, sex: 'female'},
  {name: 'Mike', age: 27, sex: 'male'}
];
```

And a filter:

```
this.peopleFilter = {age: 27, sex: 'male'};
```

Use it like:

```html
 <div *ngFor="let person of people | filter: peopleFilter;"></div>
```

As a result, two people are matching our criteria: *John* and *Mike*.

Here is the working plunker: [Multiple columns filter pipe demo.](https://plnkr.co/edit/e0PCIsqXumbXe6mAUWBI?p=preview)

Comment: When I am using it, It does not show any data and even I don't get any data when i input value.

Comment: Here is the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/e0PCIsqXumbXe6mAUWBI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I am marking your post as answer but what if there is no value (then it should return all values) or value is number in anyone input ?

Comment: Thanks! If no value is provided, say our filter is {}, then all items will be returned, otherwise it matches the exact value provided, which is fine because, for example, there might be a situation where we want to filter columns with null or undefined field. Ofc, this is a concept, and the solution may be adjusted suiting the situation.

Comment: Thanks @SeidMehmedovic. Adjusted to filter multiple values for the same key. Plunker link - https://plnkr.co/edit/bUeQHzWhDp1qnrvj3tl4

Comment: Hey, what if we have an array of objects, and inside that object, one of the attributes is an array of items e.g maybe our person has an attribute 'jobs' : ["mechanic", "scientist", "cashier"], and we want to filter based on one of those values inside the array. How would you go about doing that? @SeidMehmedovic

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did with Angular 8:

Goal: Search on multiple properties say "Property1" and "Property2" from a list of items for a given keyword:

app.module.ts:

```
......
import { MyFilterPipe } from './shared/pipes/my-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    MyFilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Pipe: content-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myFilter'
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], keyword: any, properties: string[]): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!keyword) return items;
    debugger;
    return items.filter(item => {
      var itemFound: Boolean;
      for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (item[properties[i]].toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
          itemFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      return itemFound;
    });

  }
}
```

component:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control filter-list-input" placeholder="Filter"
                  aria-label="Filter" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" >

    <div *ngFor="let itemof myItems | myFilter:searchText:['Property1', 'Property2']; let i = index">...
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class MyListComponent implements OnInit {

  ...
  searchText: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your code as below,

```
 export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: Item[], field: string, args: string): Item[]{
      let filter: string = args ? args.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
      return filter ? value.filter((item : Item) =>
          Item[field].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : value;
   }
}
```

In Html page,

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let item of items | dataFilter : columnName : value ">
```

Comment: This is just for one filter parameter. I need it for multiple parameters.

Comment: what you are exactly trying to do? Filter with single filter parameter on multiple columns or with multiple filter parameters on single column?Please, Clear it.

Comment: Multiple filter on multiple columns. I am passing data in array like `[['column1',value1],['column2',value2],['column3',value3]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have an array with columns like this:

`[{col1:"col1",col2:"col2",col3:"col3"}]`

I have also omitted all type-checkin, null-pointers, and error-handling. The current solution is an example I tried with the array:

```
myData:Array<any> = [{col1:"a",col2:"b",col3:"cadd"},
    {col1:"abba",col2:"bobba",col3:"cadd"},
    {col1:"abba",col2:"bobba",col3:"cool"},
    {col1:"a",col2:"bobba",col3:"cool"}];
```

and the pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'dataFilter'
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.filter(item =>{
      var matchesAll = true;
      for(var i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
        // check if your data contains the column and the value defined in args.
        if(item.hasOwnProperty(args[i][0]) && item[args[i][0]]==args[i][1]){
          continue;
        }else{ // at least one column did not match,
          matchesAll = false;
        }
      }
      return matchesAll;
    });
  }

}
```

You can then call

`dataFilter.transform(myData,[["col1","abba"],["col2","bobba"],["col3","cool"]]);`

in order to get one result, which is row number 3 after transformation: `[{col1:"abba",col2:"bobba",col3:"cool"}]`.

Note: You may have to adjust the names of the columns in my example to make it work with your code.

**EDIT:** With this solution, you can also pass arbitrary number of columns.

e.g `dataFilter.transform(myData,[["col3","cool"]]);`

which will result in the two last rows (from my example) after transformation:

`[{col1:"abba",col2:"bobba",col3:"cool"},{col1:"a",col2:"bobba",col3:"cool"}]`

**EDIT:** after comment stating that the code is not working, I provided a plunkr of the example above: https://plnkr.co/edit/VdpGJWyzWUVFzYNDSz1g

Comment: @JeetenParmar I added a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/VdpGJWyzWUVFzYNDSz1g please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can see the whole working **ArrayFilterPipe.ts** @ http://typescript.io/uN29xRdF1Ag or [typescriptlang.org](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20ArrayFilterPipe%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20TYPES%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09OBJECT%3A%20%27object%27%2C%0D%0A%09%09STRING%3A%20%27string%27%2C%0D%0A%09%09UNDEFINED%3A%20%27undefined%27%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20_isOfType(value%3A%20any%2C%20type%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20typeof(value)%20%3D%3D%3D%20type%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20_isUndefined(value%3A%20any)%3A%20boolean%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(value%2C%20ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.UNDEFINED)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20_isObject(value%3A%20any)%3A%20boolean%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(value%2C%20ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.OBJECT)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20_isOrHasMatch(value%3A%20any%2C%20target%3A%20any)%3A%20boolean%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(value%2C%20ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.STRING)%20%7C%7C%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(target%2C%20ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.STRING)%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3F%20value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(target.toString().toLowerCase())%20%3E%3D%200%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3A%20value%20%3D%3D%20target%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20_hasOptions(value%3A%20any%2C%20options%3A%20any)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%09(ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value)%20%7C%7C%20ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(options)%20%3F%09(ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value)%20%26%26%20ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(options))%20%0D%0A%09%09%3A%09(value%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20options%20%3D%3D%20null)%20%3F%20(value%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%26%26%20options%20%3D%3D%20null)%20%0D%0A%09%09%3A%20%09(Array.isArray(value)%20%7C%7C%20Array.isArray(options))%20%3F%20false%0D%0A%09%09%3A%20%09ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(value)%20%3F%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%09(ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(options)%09%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3F%20Object.keys(options).every(key%20%3D%3E%20value.hasOwnProperty(key)%20%26%26%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch(value%5Bkey%5D%2C%20options%5Bkey%5D))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20Object.values(value).some(val%20%3D%3E%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch(val%2C%20options)))%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%3A%20%09!ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(value)%20%3F%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%09(!ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(options)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3F%20ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch(value%2C%20options)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3A%20false)%20%0D%0A%09%09%3A%20false%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09static%20_arrayToObject(value%3A%20Array%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20(ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value)%20%7C%7C%20value%20%3D%3D%20null)%20%3F%20value%20%3A%20value.reduce((result%2C%20current)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09result%5Bcurrent%5B0%5D%5D%20%3D%20current%5B1%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09return%20result%3B%20%7D%20%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20transform(value%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%2C%20options%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09if(!value%20%7C%7C%20!Array.isArray(value)%20%7C%7C%20ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(options)%20%7C%7C%20options%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%20return%20value%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%09%09options%20%3D%20Array.isArray(options)%20%3F%20ArrayFilterPipe._arrayToObject(options)%20%3A%20options%3B%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20ArrayFilterPipe._hasOptions(item%2C%20options))%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%20%0D%0A%09TESTING%0D%0A%09--------------------------------------------------%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0Avar%20pipe%20%3D%20new%20ArrayFilterPipe()%3B%0D%0Avar%20array%20%3D%20%5Bnull%2C%20undefined%2C%20%2C%20true%2C%20123123%2C%20%27Jeke%20HeNry%27%2C%20%27joe%27%2C%20%27joe%20hen%27%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20%7B%20fake%3A%20%27hen%27%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27hen%27%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27johenrik%27%20%2C%20country%3A%20%27hen%27%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27joe%20dick%27%20%2C%20city%3A%20%27hen%27%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27Jeke%20HeNry%27%20%2C%20country%3A%20%27zxy%27%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20options%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%20REF%3A%20%20http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11403107%2Fcapturing-javascript-console-log%20*%2F%0D%0Avar%20oldLog%20%3D%20console.log%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log%20%3D%20function%20(message)%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20_arguments%20%3D%20arguments%3B%0D%0A%09var%20div%20%3D%20Object.keys(arguments).map(key%20%3D%3E%20Number(key)).reduce((result%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09result%20%3D%20result%20%7C%7C%20document.createElement(%27div%27)%3B%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09var%20isJSON%20%3D%20(_arguments%5Bkey%5D%20!%3D%20null%20%26%26%20(typeof(_arguments%5Bkey%5D)%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27object%27%20%7C%7C%20Array.isArray(_arguments%5Bkey%5D)))%3B%09%0D%0A%09%09var%20span%20%3D%20document.createElement(isJSON%20%3F%20%27pre%27%20%3A%27span%27%20)%3B%0D%0A%09%09span.innerHTML%20%3D%20isJSON%20%3F%20JSON.stringify(_arguments%5Bkey%5D%2C%20undefined)%20%3A%20_arguments%5Bkey%5D.replace(%27%5Cn%27%2C%20%27%3C%2Fbr%3E%3C%2Fbr%3E%27)%3B%0D%0A%09%09result.appendChild(span)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09return%20result%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%20null)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09document.body.appendChild(div)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20oldLog.apply(console%2C%20arguments)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0Afunction%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(%27options%27%2C%20options)%3B%0D%0A%09console.log(%27result%27%2C%20pipe.transform(array%2C%20options))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27case%20%3A%2001%27)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27---------------------------------------------------%27)%3B%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%27hen%27%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27%5Cncase%20%3A%2002%27)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27---------------------------------------------------%27)%3B%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27hen%27%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%5B%5B%27name%27%2C%20%27hen%27%5D%5D%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27%5Cncase%20%3A%2003%27)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27---------------------------------------------------%27)%3B%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27hen%27%2C%20%20country%3A%20%27hen%27%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%5B%5B%27name%27%2C%20%27hen%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27country%27%2C%20%27hen%27%5D%5D%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27%5Cncase%20%3A%2004%27)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%27---------------------------------------------------%27)%3B%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27hen%27%2C%20%20city%3A%20%27hen%27%20%2C%20fake%20%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aoptions%20%3D%20%5B%5B%27name%27%2C%20%27hen%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27country%27%2C%20%27hen%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27fake%27%2C%20true%5D%5D%3B%0D%0Atest()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)
*Also below I have attached the compile JS of the typescript for ease of seeing your desired output.* 
*Let me know if want the code commented ...*

FYI options array is cnverted to object before performing the filter, as it feels a lot comfortable that the array.

```
/* yours */
var option = [['column1',value1],['column2',value2],['column3',value3]];
/* mine */
var option = { column1: 'value1', column2: 'value2', column3: 'value3' };

static _arrayToObject(value: Array<Array<any>>): any {
    return (ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value) || value == null) 
    ? value 
    : value.reduce((result, current) => {   
                    result[current[0]] = current[1]; 
                    return result; 
                } , {});
}
```

You can also build the array/object filter similar to angular 1.x by getting some inspiration from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js

```js
var ArrayFilterPipe = (function () {
    function ArrayFilterPipe() {
    }
    ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType = function (value, type) {
        return typeof (value) === type;
    };
    ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined = function (value) {
        return ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(value, ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.UNDEFINED);
    };
    ArrayFilterPipe._isObject = function (value) {
        return ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(value, ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.OBJECT);
    };
    ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch = function (value, target) {
        return ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(value, ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.STRING) || ArrayFilterPipe._isOfType(target, ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES.STRING)
            ? value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(target.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0
            : value == target;
    };
    ArrayFilterPipe._hasOptions = function (value, options) {
        return (ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value) || ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(options) ? (ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value) && ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(options))
            : (value === null || options == null) ? (value === null && options == null)
                : (Array.isArray(value) || Array.isArray(options)) ? false
                    : ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(value) ?
                        (ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(options)
                            ? Object.keys(options).every(function (key) { return value.hasOwnProperty(key) && ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch(value[key], options[key]); })
                            : Object.values(value).some(function (val) { return ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch(val, options); }))
                        : !ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(value) ?
                            (!ArrayFilterPipe._isObject(options)
                                ? ArrayFilterPipe._isOrHasMatch(value, options)
                                : false)
                            : false);
    };
    ArrayFilterPipe._arrayToObject = function (value) {
        return (ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(value) || value == null) ? value : value.reduce(function (result, current) {
            result[current[0]] = current[1];
            return result;
        }, {});
    };
    ArrayFilterPipe.prototype.transform = function (value, options) {
        if (!value || !Array.isArray(value) || ArrayFilterPipe._isUndefined(options) || options === null) {
            return value;
        }
        options = Array.isArray(options) ? ArrayFilterPipe._arrayToObject(options) : options;
        return value.filter(function (item) { return ArrayFilterPipe._hasOptions(item, options); });
    };
    return ArrayFilterPipe;
}());
ArrayFilterPipe.TYPES = {
    OBJECT: 'object',
    STRING: 'string',
    UNDEFINED: 'undefined'
};
/*
    TESTING
    --------------------------------------------------
*/
var pipe = new ArrayFilterPipe();
var array = [null, undefined, , true, 123123, 'Jeke HeNry', 'joe', 'joe hen', {}, [], { fake: 'hen' }, { name: 'hen' }, { name: 'johenrik', country: 'hen' }, { name: 'joe dick', city: 'hen' }, { name: 'Jeke HeNry', country: 'zxy' }];
var options = null;
/* REF:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log */
var oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function (message) {
    var _arguments = arguments;
    var div = Object.keys(arguments).map(function (key) { return Number(key); }).reduce(function (result, key) {
        result = result || document.createElement('div');
        var isJSON = (_arguments[key] != null && (typeof (_arguments[key]) === 'object' || Array.isArray(_arguments[key])));
        var span = document.createElement(isJSON ? 'pre' : 'span');
        span.innerHTML = isJSON ? JSON.stringify(_arguments[key], undefined) : _arguments[key].replace('\n', '</br></br>');
        result.appendChild(span);
        return result;
    }, null);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
};
function test() {
    console.log('options', options);
    console.log('result', pipe.transform(array, options));
}
console.log('case : 01');
console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
options = 'hen';
test();
console.log('\ncase : 02');
console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
options = { name: 'hen' };
test();
options = [['name', 'hen']];
test();
console.log('\ncase : 03');
console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
options = { name: 'hen', country: 'hen' };
test();
options = [['name', 'hen'], ['country', 'hen']];
test();
console.log('\ncase : 04');
console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
options = { name: 'hen', city: 'hen', fake: true };
test();
options = [['name', 'hen'], ['country', 'hen'], ['fake', true]];
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to have a Pipe that could filter by both a specific property value AND a generic value called "All". A user could adjust these filters dynamically by selecting them from a dropdown (thus the use of the more inefficient `pure: false` config).

In the component (had to default to 'All')

```
public filters = { status: "All", condition: "All", other: "All" };
```

In the template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filter:filters">
```

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<any>, filter: {[key: string]: any }): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => {
      let matches = Object.keys(filter).every(f => {
        return filter[f] === 'All' || item[f] == filter[f];
      })

      return matches;
    })
  }
}
```