# How to do a global search in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm a new developper in angular2 and I want to do a global search in an array of json objects. For example, this array :

```ts
invoiceList = 
  [
    {
      invoiceNumber: 1234, 
      invoiceSupplier: "test", 
      invoiceStatus: "Import error", 
      invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR", 
      date: "22/01/2017", 
      amount : 134527
    },
    ...
  ];
```

And I want to do my search like that : 
[image]

The problem and the difficulty here is that :

- I want to search depending only on some values (ex : status, supplier name, number...) and display OTHER fields (like date, net amount etc..).
- I want to order by the final results depending on some values (ex: number, supplier, date and amount). And I don't how to do that in angular2.
- Finally, I want to do an "equivalent" of ng-show in angular2? I mean that I want to display the table only if we press search button, and if we click on cancel, it will remove it.

I know that it was simple to do that in angular 1, we can use filters, 'orderBy' and things like that but apparently in angular2, we can't do that and I got very very confused. Can you help me to solve that please???

here is my component code :

```ts
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html'
  })
  export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  invoiceList = [{invoiceNumber:  1234, invoiceSupplier : "test", invoiceStatus : "Import error", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR", date : "22/01/2017", amount : 134527}, 
  {invoiceNumber:  15672, invoiceSupplier : "test11", invoiceStatus : "Import error", invoiceCategory: "invoice without PO", date : "02/01/2017", amount : 134.3},
  {invoiceNumber:  99863, invoiceSupplier : "test22", invoiceStatus : "Other Document", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR", date : "10/12/2016", amount : 189},
  {invoiceNumber:  24561, invoiceSupplier : "test50", invoiceStatus : "Other Document", invoiceCategory: "invoice without PO", date : "15/01/2017", amount : -134527},
  ];


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  }
```

and my html code :

```html
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Invoice Number :</td>
        <td>
          <input name="invoiceNumber">
        </td>

        <td>Invoice Supplier Name :</td>
        <td>
          <input name="invoiceSupplier">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Invoice Status :</td>
        <td>
          <select name="invoiceStatus">

            <option></option>
            <option> Import error </option>
            <option> Invoice control required </option>
            <option>Rejected from SAP </option>
            <option>Other Document </option>
            <option> Invoice created manually in SAP </option>
            <option>To be integrated in SAP </option>
            <option> Integrated in SAP </option>
            <option> Booked in SAP </option>
            <option>Paid in SAP</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>Invoice Category :</td>
        <td>

          <select name="invoiceCategory">
            <option></option>
            <option>Invoice with GR</option>
            <option>Invoice without GR</option>
            <option>Invoice without PO</option>

          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Order :</td>
        <td>
          <select name="order">

            <option> Number </option>
            <option> Supplier </option>
            <option> Date </option>
            <option> Net Amount </option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="detail">
            <button type="reset">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
```

I know that I didn't do anything so far, but I'm really new at angular2, and I really got confused. Can you help me please at least with the component part???

Thank you in advance !

Comment: In other words, what I want to do here is to do an AND search depending on 3 values (3 "variables") but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: This question looks fairly similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672578/filter-on-multiple-colums-using-one-pipe-angular-2). Try to adapt your code with the example in one of the answers. (here is the answer proposed by me in the other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41738576/1471485)

Answer (score 2):

**DONE !!** -  [**see@PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/u2sPdTAuAxPCPeaQhgBj?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: 'src/search.component.html'
})
export class SearchComponent{

 invoiceList = [
  {invoiceNumber:  1234, invoiceSupplier : "test", invoiceStatus : "Import error", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR", date : "22/01/2017", amount : 134527}, 
  {invoiceNumber:  15672, invoiceSupplier : "test11", invoiceStatus : "Import error", invoiceCategory: "invoice without PO", date : "02/01/2017", amount : 134.3},
  {invoiceNumber:  99863, invoiceSupplier : "test22", invoiceStatus : "Other Document", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR", date : "10/12/2016", amount : 189},
  {invoiceNumber:  24561, invoiceSupplier : "test50", invoiceStatus : "Other Document", invoiceCategory: "invoice without PO", date : "15/01/2017", amount : -134527},
 ];

 invoiceCats = [];
 invoiceStatuses = [];
 invoiceNumbers = [];
 invoiceFields = Object.keys(this.invoiceList[0]);

 invoiceStatus = "";
 invoiceCategory = "";
 invoiceNumber;
 invoiceSupplier;
 order = this.invoiceFields[0];

 searchResults = [];

 constructor() { 
   this.invoiceList.forEach(i => {
     if(this.invoiceCats.indexOf(i.invoiceCategory) === -1) {
      this.invoiceCats.push(i.invoiceCategory);
     }

     if(this.invoiceStatuses.indexOf(i.invoiceStatus) === -1) {
      this.invoiceStatuses.push(i.invoiceStatus);
     }

     this.invoiceNumbers.push(i.invoiceNumber);
   })
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 searchNow(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.searchResults = this.invoiceList.filter(i => {
     return (this.invoiceStatus ? i.invoiceStatus === this.invoiceStatus : true) 
        &&  (this.invoiceNumber ? i.invoiceNumber === this.invoiceNumber : true)
        &&  (this.invoiceSupplier ? i.invoiceSupplier === this.invoiceSupplier : true)
        &&  (this.invoiceCategory ? i.invoiceCategory === this.invoiceCategory : true)
   }).sort((a, b) => {
      if(['invoiceNumber', 'amount'].indexOf(this.order) > -1) return a[this.order] - b[this.order];
      if(['invoiceSupplier', 'invoiceStatus', 'invoiceCategory'].indexOf(this.order) > -1) return (a[this.order] == [a[this.order], b[this.order]].sort()[1] ? 1 : -1);
      if(this.order === 'date') {
        const x = new Date(a.date.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
        const y = new Date(b.date.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
        return x.getTime() - y.getTime();
      }
   })
 }

}
```

Note: The code inside constructor is just to generate meta Data.

```
 <form (submit)="searchNow($event)">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Invoice Number :</td>
        <td>
          <input name="invoiceNumber" [(ngModel)]="invoiceNumber" type="number">
        </td>

        <td>Invoice Supplier Name :</td>
        <td>
          <input name="invoiceSupplier" [(ngModel)]="invoiceSupplier" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Invoice Status :</td>
        <td>
          <select name="invoiceStatus" [(ngModel)]="invoiceStatus">
            <option value="">Any</option>
            <option *ngFor="let iS of invoiceStatuses" [value]="iS">{{iS}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>Invoice Category :</td>
        <td>

          <select name="invoiceCategory" [(ngModel)]="invoiceCategory">
            <option value="">Any</option>
            <option *ngFor="let iC of invoiceCats" [value]="iC">{{iC}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Order By:</td>
        <td>
          <select name="order" [(ngModel)]="order">
            <option *ngFor="let iF of invoiceFields" [value]="iF">{{iF}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="detail">
            <button type="reset">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>

  <div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of searchResults">Number: {{i.invoiceNumber}},  Supplier: {{i.invoiceSupplier}}, Date: {{i.date}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Note: There are many if not hundreds of ways to play with forms in `Angular2` you can use whichever you like, I just used the easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

Not complete but to give you the base ...

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Invoice {
    invoiceNumber: number;
    invoiceSupplier: string;
    invoiceStatus: string;
    invoiceCategory: string;
    date: string;
    amount: number
}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div></div>
    `,
    styleUrls: []
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.invoiceList = [ {invoiceNumber: 1231, invoiceSupplier: "test1", invoiceStatus: "Import error3", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR1", date: "22/01/2017", amount : 134527 },
                             {invoiceNumber: 1232, invoiceSupplier: "test1", invoiceStatus: "Import error2", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR2", date: "22/01/2017", amount : 134527 },
                             {invoiceNumber: 1233, invoiceSupplier: "test2", invoiceStatus: "Import error1", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR1", date: "22/01/2017", amount : 134527 },
                             {invoiceNumber: 1234, invoiceSupplier: "test3", invoiceStatus: "Import error3", invoiceCategory: "invoice with GR3", date: "22/01/2017", amount : 134527 },
                          ];

        //this.invoiceFilter.invoiceNumber = 1234;
        //this.invoiceFilter.invoiceSupplier = "test2";
        this.invoiceFilter.invoiceCategory = "invoice with GR2";

        let filterdeInvoices = this.filterInvoices(this.invoiceList, this.invoiceFilter);
        console.log(filterdeInvoices);
        this.fieldToSortBy = "invoiceNumber";
        let sortedInvoices = this.sortInvoices(filterdeInvoices, this.fieldToSortBy);
        console.log(sortedInvoices);
    }

    invoiceFilter = new Invoice();
    fieldToSortBy: string;
    invoiceList: Invoice[];

    filterInvoices(invoiceList:Invoice[], invoiceFilter: Invoice): Invoice[]         {        
        return invoiceList.filter((invoice) => (invoiceFilter.invoiceNumber ? invoiceFilter.invoiceNumber === invoice.invoiceNumber : true) &&
                                               (invoiceFilter.invoiceSupplier ? invoiceFilter.invoiceSupplier === invoice.invoiceSupplier : true) &&
                                               (invoiceFilter.invoiceStatus ? invoiceFilter.invoiceStatus === invoice.invoiceStatus : true) &&
                                               (invoiceFilter.invoiceCategory ? invoiceFilter.invoiceCategory === invoice.invoiceCategory : true));
    }

    sortInvoices(invoiceList:Invoice[], fieldToSortBy: string): Invoice[] {
        return invoiceList.sort((inv1, inv2) => (inv1[fieldToSortBy] > inv2[fieldToSortBy] ? 1 : -1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a `Pipe` for filtering stuff like this.

Your `Pipe` could look like this:

1. check incoming variables
2. filter your invoices
3. order them if required

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(invoices: Invoice[], searchOptions: any): Invoice[] {
    if (!invoices || !invoices.length) return [];
    if (!searchOptions) return [];

    let filtered = invoices.filter(i => {
      return i &&
             (!searchOptions.number || i.invoiceNumber.toString().indexOf(searchOptions.number) >= 0) &&
             (!searchOptions.name || i.invoiceSupplier.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchOptions.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0) &&
             (!searchOptions.status || i.invoiceStatus === searchOptions.status) &&
             (!searchOptions.category || i.invoiceCategory === searchOptions.category);
    });

    let orderBy = searchOptions.orderBy;
    if (!orderBy) return filtered;

    /* credits for sorting goes to: 'Ankit Singh' ! :) */
    return filtered.sort((a, b) => {

      switch (orderBy) {
        default: return 0;

        case 'invoiceNumber':
        case 'amount':
          return a[orderBy] - b[orderBy];
        case 'invoiceSupplier':
        case 'invoiceStatus':
        case 'invoiceCategory':
          return (a[orderBy] == [a[orderBy], b[orderBy]].sort()[1] ? 1 : -1);
        case 'date': {
          const x = new Date(a.date.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
          const y = new Date(b.date.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
          return x.getTime() - y.getTime();
        }
      }
   });
  }
}
```

And use this `Pipe` the following way:

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceList | filter:searchOptions">
  <div>{{ invoice.invoiceNumber }}</div>
  <div>{{ invoice.invoiceSupplier }}</div>
  <div>{{ invoice.date }}</div>
  <div>{{ invoice.amount }}</div>
</div>
```

Those `searchOptions` is an object coming from our form:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput ngModel name="name" placeholder="Invoice supplier name">
</md-input-container>

<md-select placeholder="Invoice status" ngModel name="status">
  <md-option *ngFor="let status of statusArray" [value]="status.val">
    {{ status.name}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>

<md-select placeholder="Invoice category" ngModel name="category">
  <md-option *ngFor="let category of categoryArray" [value]="category.val">
    {{ category.name}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>

<md-select placeholder="order by" ngModel name="orderBy">
  <md-option *ngFor="let key of invoiceKeyArray" [value]="key.val">
    {{ key.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>

<button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="searchOptions = f.value">search</button>
<button md-raised-button color="accent" (click)="resetForm(f);">reset</button>
```

live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/VPTnIOpieKt3YLqsEncr?p=preview