# flexible pipe to filter objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

i am trying to make a flexible pipe to filter my array of objects to display it with *ngFor

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let item of items | myFilter:property:true">
```

for example i want to show div only for object with true property :

```
[
{'name':'first', 'property': 'true'}, 
{'name':'last', 'property': 'false'}
]
```

It seems not to work when i try to set property dynamically like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
name: 'myFilter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(items: any[], key: any, value: any): any {
         return items.filter(item => item[key] === value ? item : null);
     }
}
```

I tried also this

```
item['"' + key + '"']
```

and this (with es6 template strings)

```
item[`"$key"`]
```

but this pipe works well if i call property straight like this

```
item.property
```

And i really need to make it more flexible, because i have a lot of situations in my app where i need to filter items by different properties values

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672578/filter-on-multiple-columns-using-one-pipe-angular-2/41841674#41841674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipe is definitely correct, you are just missing the `''` on your HTML. Try to call it like this: `<div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let item of items | myFilter:'property':true">` and it will work perfectly. This is because the pipe expects a string, but you are giving an object reference. property != 'property'

Comment: Happy it helped :)

Comment: Remember that is the same for the key value, if you want to compare strings and not boolean, you have to use the '' :)

Comment: item['"' + key + '"'] and item['"' + key + '"']

Comment: i mean item['"' + key + '"']  and item[`"$key"`] , because i tried to solve this problem like you but in different way, to not add '' in html

Comment: Because by writing "myFilter : property" you are passing to you key value an object called "property", that does not exist, is undefined. Instead you have to pass a string that contains the effective value you want to compare

Comment: "property" is a string with value "property"
property is an object called property with value undefined because it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter` expects your filter function to return a `boolean`, meaning that you should change your filter for this:

```
transform(items: any[], key: any, value: any): any {
     return items.filter(item => item[key] === value);
 }
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)

Comment: thx for correction, but it still not work. As i said, it was working with straight property calling

Comment: you should probably check if item[property] exists using a console.log just before the return (check with console.log(items[0][property]))