# Searching in multiple columns angular2

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a textarea for searching a table, all in an angular2 application with bootstrap.

My code was searching in one column, now I want the search term to be looked up across two columns, and the user will see all the matched table rows highlighted.

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" id="search" [(ngModel)]="searchString" type="text" placeholder="Search by Book ID.." style="float:right;"
  value="">

<tr *ngFor="let books of bookDetails |jobsearch:{ bookId: searchString} : false | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 50, currentPage: p };">
```

The other column that I want to be searched is 'bookName'.

Comment: What is the «jobsearch» pipe? You could just write a custom pipe that filters based on your logic

Comment: this link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672578/filter-on-multiple-columns-using-one-pipe-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom pipe example:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'booksearch'
})
export class BookSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Array<any>, filter: {[key: string]: any }): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => {
            let noMatch = Object.keys(filter)
            .find(key => item[key] !== filter[key]);

            return !noMatch;
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<tr *ngFor="let books of bookDetails |booksearch:{ bookId: searchString, bookname: searchString }”>
```