# How can read browser error using javascript or angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I need to append these error in the log file on back-end. These error are not captured in angular2. How can read these error?[image: Browser console snapshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Capturing javascript console.log?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)

Comment: @abhishekkannojia They are overriding console.log but i don't have put console.log anywhere. What i want is on some interval i will read the full browser console then will push it to backend.

Comment: following post is a must-read because it point out the cross-browser issues related to `window.onerror`: [Capture and report JavaScript errors with window.onerror](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror.html)

Answer (score 11):

As explained in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror), you can catch Javascript runtime errors in a `window.onerror` event handler, and catch resource loading errors in a capturing event handler defined with `window.addEventListener("error", fn, true)`.

A service could set these event handlers and record the errors in an array. You would send the content of the array to the server when you want. The service could look like this:

```
export class ErrorLogService {

    private errors = new Array<any>();

    constructor() {
        let that = this;
        window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
            let string = msg.toLowerCase();
            let substring = "script error";
            if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
                console.log("Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail");
            } else {
                that.errors.push({
                    message: msg,
                    url: url,
                    line: lineNo,
                    column: columnNo,
                    error: error
                });
            }
            return false;
        };
        window.document.addEventListener("error", (event: ErrorEvent) => {
            if (event.target && (event.target as any).src) {
                let url = (event.target as any).src;
                this.errors.push({
                    message: "Resource not found",
                    url: url
                });
            } else {
                this.errors.push({
                    message: "Unknown error",
                    error: event
                });
            }
        }, true);
    }
}
```

The error detection mechanism can be tested in **[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/47qjgksz/4/)**.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use the following code**

```
(function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

if(!data) {
    console.error('Console.save: No data')
    return;
}

if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

if(typeof data === "object"){
    data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
}

var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
    e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
    a    = document.createElement('a')

a.download = filename
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, 
false, false, 0, null)
a.dispatchEvent(e)
}
})(console)
```

**source : https://plus.google.com/u/0/+UmarHansa/posts/G3VZ9sG9SCH**