# How to get whole console output in javascript?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

i searched a lot of things and i tried most of them but still i could not solve my problem.
What i want to do: I want to get current console output when i click the button.
Sometimes there are XHR errors like this one [image: console_error]

I want to get even this xhr info in string. Basically i want to get whole stuff in console. Not only logs, not only warnings or not only errors.
Is that possible ? If so, how can i do that ? Thank you.

Comment: No, that's not possible from inside the web page. The console is for debugging, and has access to sensitive information.

Comment: You can, more or less, achieve that by [**hijacking `console.*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11403107/6647153) and [**listening for global errors**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951791/6647153).