# Save / export Chrome's JavaScript console input history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there anyway that I can save or export the history of JavaScript console *input* (console history) in Google Chrome? I'm not looking to save the output or the errors, so hovering my mouse over the console box, right-clicking, and selecting `Save as...` is not the solution. I don't want to have to scroll up with the arrow keys and copy-and-paste the contents each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)

Comment: You really ought to [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) some of the fine answers you've received to the [94 questions you've asked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953537/melab?tab=questions). **Asking 94 questions and accepting 0 of the fine answers you've received** (and only ever upvoting twice in 5 years) shows a lack of appreciation for the help you've received and failure to help future readers. It's not too late to fix this situation. You should do so now, starting with @SalmanA's answer here.

Answer (score 49):

I figured out a weird solution that seems to work:

- Open Chrome Developer Tools (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>)
- If the developer tools window is docked, undock into a separate window (open the **`⋮`** menu to choose docking option)
- Inside the developer tools window, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> which will open a developer tools window ***for the developer tools window!***
- Inside the second developer tools window, enter the following command inside console:
  `localStorage.getItem("consoleHistory")`

This should print the console history, encoded as JSON inside the console. You can decode the JSON into an array using this command:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("consoleHistory"))
```

Or copy the JSON to clipboard using:

```
copy(localStorage.getItem("consoleHistory"))
```

Comment: Great workaround, but tedious. I fiddled around and found a way which does not require undocking and has less steps. Create a bookmark to `devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html` for easy access (or paste it in a new tab). Whenever you want to get the history, go to that page, open the console _(DON'T use the one already displayed)_, and paste `copy(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("consoleHistory")).join('\n'))`

Answer (score 0):

`consoleHistory` in localStorage keeps only the most recent 300 records, and older records appear to have been deleted.