# How do I capture console logs in chrome browser in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is a snippet code that I have written for log, error, warn and debug.
How can I see the stored values in my browser?

```
            let defaultLog = console.log.bind(console);
            let defaultError = console.error.bind(console);
            let defaultWarn = console.warn.bind(console);
            let defaultDebug = console.debug.bind(console);
            console.log = function () {
                defaultLog.apply(console, arguments);
                this.consoleLogCapture.push({'type': 'log', 'value': Array.from(arguments)});
            };
            console.error = function () {
               defaultError.apply(console, arguments);
               this.consoleLogCapture.push({'type': 'error', 'value': Array.from(arguments)});
           };
            this.sessionStore.setConsoleCapture(this.consoleLogCapture);
```

Comment: Is there a question here ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the above code but when I'm trying to get the captured consoled but I havn't get the data intead I'm getting undefined.

Comment: Here, you just adding useless complexity to your code, and it doesn't even work.

Comment: If you know to suggest a better way.
And also stop these kinds of replies.

Comment: I did suggest it, and sure, good luck with your issue !

Comment: Do you have a sample for this? If Yes, Can you please paste here

Comment: [here](https://codemag.com/Article/1711021/Logging-in-Angular-Applications) there are a good approach to manage logs using a service

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I don't get what are you missing. Can you add snippet or jsfiddle with your problem?

```js
let consoleLogCapture = [];
let defaultLog = console.log.bind(console);
            let defaultError = console.error.bind(console);
            console.log = function () {
                defaultLog.apply(console, arguments);
                consoleLogCapture.push({'type': 'log', 'value': Array.from(arguments)});
            };
            console.error = function () {
               defaultError.apply(console, arguments);
               consoleLogCapture.push({'type': 'error', 'value': Array.from(arguments)});
           };
           console.log('some');
           console.log(consoleLogCapture);
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error.
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Actually you'll have to initialize the variable with an empty array, As I did above in 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

I have published a small [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-console-logs) for the same use case.

You can use it like so.

```js
const cc = new CaptureConsole();
cc.start()

console.log("simple log")
console.info("informative log", {a:1})
console.error(new Error("Our small petty error"))
console.warn("Better Watch Out!")
console.debug("please work1")

cc.stop()
console.log(cc.getCaptures());
```

The output is captured as such

```bash
[
  { function: 'log', args: [ 'simple log' ], ts: 1673463210311 },
  {
    function: 'info',
    args: [ 'informative log', '{"a":1}' ],
    ts: 1673463210311
  },
  {
    function: 'error',
    args: [
      '{"stack":"Error: Our small petty error\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/navdeep/Desktop/nsr/test/me/index.js:10:15)\\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)\\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)\\n    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)\\n    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)\\n    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)\\n    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47","message":"Our small petty error"}'
    ],
    ts: 1673463210312
  },
  {
    function: 'warn',
    args: [ 'Better Watch Out!' ],
    ts: 1673463210312
  },
  { function: 'debug', args: [ 'please work1' ], ts: 1673463210312 }
]
```