# Is it possible to read from the terminal using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, terminal, cypress

I would like to use console log data in my test. After I register my user an enrollment email URL is generated and I need this in my test case.

Comment: This is not a lot of detail. Could you elaborate? How does the enrollment email URL relate to reading from the terminal?

Comment: After the new user is registered a verification email is sent out to the registered email address. I couldn't find any free email services that can simulate a virtual email address for me so I use the enrollment URL to see if it is actually leads to the current path so the user can finish the registration by giving a password. This URL is logged in terminal  and it contains a unique token. I would like to use this URL in Cypress so I can simulate the registration process,

Comment: Does [Capturing javascript console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11403146/3113485) answer your question?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-spy-on-console-log? But that system seems very insecure, the point of sending the email is to validate that's a real email address that the registering user controls.